# string::replace not working correctly 100% of the time?

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm trying to replace every space character with '%20' in a string, and I'm thinking of using the built in replace function for the string class.

Currently, I have:

```
void replaceSpace(string& s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    string str = "%20";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            s.replace(i, 1, str);
        }
    }

}
```

When I pass in the string "_a_b_c_e_f_g__", where the underscores represent space, my output is "%20a%20b%20c%20e_f_g__". Again, underscores represent space.

Why is that the spaces near the beginning of the string are replaced, but the spaces towards the end aren't?

Answer (score 8):

You are making `s` longer with each replacement, but you are not updating `len` which is used in the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the string that you are just scanning is like cutting the branch under your feet. It may work if you are careful, but in this case you aren't.

Namely, you take the string `len` at the beginning but with each replacement your string gets longer and you are pushing the replacement places further away (so you never reach all of them).

The correct way to cut this branch is from its end (tip) towards the trunk - this way you always have a safe footing:

```
void replaceSpace(string& s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    string str = "%20";
    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            s.replace(i, 1, str);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're growing the string but only looping to its initial size.

Looping over a collection while modifying it is very prone to error.

Here's a solution that doesn't:

```
void replace(string& s)
{
    string s1;
    std::for_each(s.begin(),
                  s.end(),
                  [&](char c) {
                      if (c == ' ') s1 += "%20";
                      else s1 += c;
                  });
    s.swap(s1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the problem is you're using the initial string length in your loop, but the string gets bigger along the way. Your loop never reaches the end of the string.

You have a number of ways to fix this. You can correct your solution and make sure you go to the end of the string as it is now, not as it was before you started looping.
Or you can use @molbdnilo 's way, which creates a copy of the string along the way.
Or you can use something like this:

```
std::string input =  " a b c e f g  ";

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = input.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    input.replace(pos, 1, "%20");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can make it easier for you:

```
string replace_char_str(string str, string find_str, string replace_str)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    for ( pos = str.find(find_str); pos != std::string::npos; pos = str.find(find_str,pos) )
     {
         str.replace(pos ,1, replace_str);
     }
     return str;
}
```

So if when you want to replace the spaces, try it like this:

```
string new_str = replace_char_str(yourstring, " ", "%20");
```

Hope this helps you ! :)